# Create an OrderItem OR Link a LineItem to an Order in a simple e-commerce database?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I'm building my own e-commerce system from scratch using the django-rest-framework.

Here is a description of my system architecture:

Db format = PostgresSQL

One **Account** has many **LineItems** (aka CartItems).

One **LineItem** has one **Account** (FK), one **Product** (FK)

One **Account** has many **Orders**

---

**LineItem Fields:**

- Account FK
- Product FK
- Quantity
- Price (Serializer method field to factor in any discounts (range 0-1) specified the product model).

---

My Issue lies with the account being able to create an order.

I have identified two ways so far:

1) Modify the **LineItem** Model by adding the following fields:

- IsMountedForOrder (for buy now purposes) - BooleanField
- Order (Foreign Key)

**Constraint**: The LineItems Model becomes overburdened with Foreign Keys and relationships - it seems like going to be a hindrance from a DB management standpoint. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

2) Create an OrderItem Model (One **Order** has Many **OrderItems**)

Fields:

- Order FK
- Product FK (Parsed from owned LineItems)
- Quantity (Parsed from owned LineItems)
- Price (Parsed from owned LineItems)

and upon creation of a successful order, the lineItems will be deleted.

**Constraints**: There is a duplication of Data for a short duration and seems like unnecessary computation - therefore adding latency to the service.

I would appreciate any suggestions in how I can achieve an efficient order creation method. 
Either by modifying the two methods or identifying any architecture flaws I might have overlooked. Thank you!

Comment: This is one question in the subject, and many questions in the body.  To answer the subject:  FKs are limited only by your database, so add as many as you want.  There is a performance hit on insert/update for each one, but no issue for small tables.

Comment: I have noted the flaw in my question format (I am new to this), and have edited accordingly. Thank you for the answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the level of complexity in your e-commerce system, I would aim my design to be something similar to this:

```
1. Account
2. Order { account_id, total, tax, address, etc}
3. OrderLine { order_id, product_id, price, discount, quantity_ordered, quantity_fulfilled, etc}
4. Cart { account_id, subtotal, tax, coupons, is_abandoned, address, etc}
5. CartLine { cart_id, product_id, price, discount, quantity, etc}
```

Typically you do not want to create OrderLine until an order has been placed. If you're storing Cart information on the server, create a separate table to maintain those.

Once a user adds items to their Cart, update the Cart/CartLine. After they proceed to checkout and are finished with their payment, take the Cart (+CartLine) object and create an Order (+OrderLine) from it.

If you want to decrease this complexity by a bit, I would recommend to not store Cart information in a table, and simply use `request.session` to store cart info.

When the user completes their order, convert the cart into an Order+OrderLine.

If you want more freedom (with increased complexity) instead of Cart + CartLine, I would use Checkout + CheckoutLine tables which store more information that just the cart (things like which step the customer has reached in their checkout process, payment info, etc.)

I hope that answers some of your queries based on my understanding of your question.

Comment: This definitely helped, thanks for taking out the time to write this! I actually ended up using something similar to the checkout + checkoutLine functionality - created associations with the order model to the lineItem models, with status updates. This slightly increases complexity but its worth the tradeoff as it simplifies the system and will be able to scale efficiently when the time comes! Appreciate the help a lot!  Cheers

Comment: @Rishi Surana I'm glad I could help. If this helped you I would appreciate if you could select this as an answer and close the question :)